# How to add my dictionary into Stanford tagger?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a list of words, and I want the tagger to tag all of them as a noun. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: check out this https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2012-June/002204.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I didn't mean segmentation, and in fact I have segmented it. My question is how to give a tag for a list of particular words?

Answer (score 1):

You need to train your tagger with your custom dictionary (I have a list of words, and I want the tagger to tag all of them as a noun.) . To do that you have to change the .props file. props file contain the options for the tagger to use.

In the **props file** you have **to change  training file**.
you can get more details [HERE](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#train)

trainFile = custome-tagged-dictionary.appropriateExtension

Comment: But my list is not very large. How can I train a tagger based on the existing tagger? Or where can I get the corpus which is used to train the existing tagger? So that I can add my own words.

Comment: check your .props file , you will get the name of the existing corpus file

Comment: Yep, I have seen the files name. But I just don't know where are them. For example, where is '/u/nlp/data/chinese/ctb7/train.mrg' ?

Comment: Hi the resource you are requesting is distributed by the LDC.  To acquire it you must go through the LDC.  Here is the link:    https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T21